# How can I compile a Delphi application without using the IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I need to build the components, package, and project file without using the Delphi XE7 RAD Studio IDE. Is there some way to do this using command line instead?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done, for instance, a Google search for "compile delphi command line"?

Comment: Well! I tried dcc32 -B command and give the  entire  project path as given embarcadero website but I found an error dcu file not found

Answer (score 4):

- When you installed RAD Studio, it added a shortcut in the start menu named *RAD Studio Command Prompt*. Execute that shortcut. You now have a command prompt window for an environment that includes all you need to build at the comment line.
- Change directory to the directory containing your .dproj files.
- Execute the following command: `msbuild YourProjectName.dproj`.
- If you have multiple projects build them all. Of course you'd want to script all this up in due course.
- Control the build target (clean, make, build) and configuration (debug, release, win32, win64) using command line arguments as documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command

For more details, start with the documentation here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MSBuild_Overview

Comment: That was very much helpful.But,I am looking  scripting up all those things in a configuration file which can build the corresponding EXE files from scratch using an environment/computer without any existing installation of packages.Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: You have to decide on a preferred scripting technique. That's really a separate issue to the question you asked. You could do it simply with a .bat command script. I personally do it with Python scripts. There are many other ways. The choice is yours.

Comment: Well how delightful, I open the shortcut to the RAD Studio Command Prompt, and it immediately gives me "Not enough storage is available to process this command." Way to go Emba :-/

Comment: @Jerry: That's an issue with your machine, not the shortcut. The shortcut simply opens a command prompt and sets some environmental variables. (Confirm it - right-click and view properties.) If your machine doesn't have enough space in the path or something else, that's hardly EMBT's fault. You're doing the equivalent of "I threw my monitor away, and now I can't see what Windows is doing. Microsoft broke my computer!!!"